# Equivalent pyspark's json.loads function for spark-shell

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I am working with json files in spark-shell. My goal is to parse json (i.e. select specific fields) into RDD. In pyspark, I can simply use `json.loads`:

```
import json
docs = (sc.textFile("file.json") 
          .map(lambda x: (json.loads(x)['url'], json.loads(x)['content'])) )
```

One solution I've found so far is using `read.json`. However, it returns dataframe.

```
val docs = sqlContext.
           read.json("file.json").
           select("url", "content").
           as[(String, String)].rdd
```

Is there any equivalent pyspark's json.loads can be implemented in spark-shell (scala)?

Comment: you can use red.json method in spark shell also

Comment: @RajatMishra yes, `read.json` can be used, but it outs dataframe

Comment: Youcan always convert the dataframe back to rdd and then map it to whatever you need. dataframe has an "rdd" member which results in RDD[Row]

Comment: @AssafMendelson thank you, it is what I've done. Is there any function in scala to parse json directly into rdd, instead into dataframe?

Comment: Any java json package can be used to convert a json line to object. you would use it very similar to how you used json.loads. The most common is jackson which I believe is the backend of the dataframe read. The problem is that because scala(java) is statically typed it would be more complicated to use than python. Any reason you want rdd and not dataframe?