# Read external json file into RDD and extract specific values in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Firstly, I am completely new to scala and spark Although bit famailiar with pyspark. I am working with external json file which is pretty huge and I am not allowed to convert it into dataset or dataframe. I have to perform operations on pure RDD.

So I wanted to know how can I get specific value of key. So I read my json file as `sc.textFile("information.json")` Now normally in python I would do like

```
x = sc.textFile("information.json").map(lambda x: json.loads(x))\ 
 .map(lambda x: (x['name'],x['roll_no'])).collect()
```

is there any equivalent of above code in scala (Extracting value of specific keys) in RDD without converting to dataframe or dataset.

Essentially same question as [Equivalent pyspark's json.loads function for spark-shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41865420/equivalent-pysparks-json-loads-function-for-spark-shell) but hoping to get more concrete and noob friendly answer. Thank you

Json data:
`{"name":"ABC", "roll_no":"12", "Major":"CS"}`

Comment: Can you give an example of your json please ?

Comment: Updated with JSON data

Comment: My answer on how to parse Json with scala should help you

Comment: is there any specific reason for not using `spark.read.json`? then you dont need to do any custom parsing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1: RDD API + json4s lib**

One way is using the [json4s](https://nosqlnocry.wordpress.com/2015/04/16/working-with-json-in-scala-using-the-json4s-library-part-one/) library. The library is already used internally by Spark.

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._

// {"name":"ABC1", "roll_no":"12", "Major":"CS1"}
// {"name":"ABC2", "roll_no":"13", "Major":"CS2"}
// {"name":"ABC3", "roll_no":"14", "Major":"CS3"}
val file_location = "information.json"

val rdd = sc.textFile(file_location)

rdd.map{ row =>
  val json_row = parse(row)

  (compact(json_row \ "name"), compact(json_row \ "roll_no"))
}.collect().foreach{println _}

// Output
// ("ABC1","12")
// ("ABC2","13")
// ("ABC3","14")
```

First we parse the row data into json_row then we access the properties of the row with the operator `\` i.e: `json_row \ "name"`. The final result is a sequence of tuples of `name,roll_no`

**Option 2: dataframe API + get_json_object()**

And a more straight forward approach would be via the dataframe API in combination with the `get_json_object()` function.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.get_json_object

val df = spark.read.text(file_location)

df.select(
  get_json_object($"value","$.name").as("name"),
  get_json_object($"value","$.roll_no").as("roll_no"))
.collect()
.foreach{println _}

// [ABC1,12]
// [ABC2,13]
// [ABC3,14]
```

Comment: Hello there @Max, did the solution above work for you?

Comment: It did. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

i used to parse json in scala with this kind of method :

```
 /** ---------------------------------------
    * Example of method to parse simple json
        {
        "fields": [
          {
            "field1": "value",
            "field2": "value",
            "field3": "value"
          }
        ]
      }*/

import scala.io.Source
import scala.util.parsing.json._

  case class outputData(field1 : String, field2: String, field3 : String)

  def singleMapJsonParser(JsonDataFile : String) : List[outputData] = {

    val JsonData : String = Source.fromFile(JsonDataFile).getLines.mkString

    val jsonFormatData = JSON.parseFull(JsonData).map{
      case json : Map[String, List[Map[String,String]]] =>
        json("fields").map(v => outputData(v("field1"),v("field2"),v("field3")))
    }.get

    jsonFormatData
  }
```

Then you just have to call your sparkContext to transform le List[Class] output to RDD